# GIF Image display using WebView

Tags: android, gif, android-webview

Can someone please provide a code to display GIF images in a webview ( I'm already able to display the same using frame animation of png images) Now I want a way to display the GIF images rather than loading the frames or drawing the images again and again!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gifs are supported in web view.

write a html file as following :

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <font color="gray">Some text you display</font>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <img src="yourGIF.gif">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

and store it in "assets" folder of you application also store your gif in the same folder. And do following to show it:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/your_html.html");
```

Comment: I did the same as you told.. The GIF is seen clearly in the workspace window of Eclipse whereas.. only the first frame of the GIF is shown in the emulator display (#no animation!)

Comment: the same thing works in Android Email application. A spinner spins before message gets loaded. Is there any thing to set to webview?

Comment: It helps to show gif but it does not make gif(or webview) fix in the linear layout allocated to it rather if the image is lager than the size allocated to it. the webview appears with scroll. Please suggest a way to avoid scroll and fix webview in linear layout.

Comment: what if my gif file is not from is drawable or asset folder?

Answer (score 27):

Try this..

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/anim5.gif");
```

Simply call your GIF image from assets like this..

Comment: This displays the gif. However, it costs some time to make the GIF visible. How can I show the GIF immediately?

Comment: Where is a good place to put the `android_asset` directory within my project? The syntax `file:///android_asset` leads me to believe that `android_asset` is in the root directory of your filesystem, but that won't work if I want to check in the asset to my repo...

Comment: Works, but the problem here is that the image may appear too small or cropped. Solution above fixes that, I guess. I used this HTML to resize and center the image: `<html><head><style>body { margin: 0; } img { height: 100%; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }</style></head><body><img src="{{imgUrl}}"></body></html>`

Comment: Just in case if you want to make your GIF fit to your layout.             
WebVIew wb = new WebView(this)                                                                     wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverViewMode(true)                                           wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11962112/3260008 <-- this is useful if someone is curious to "file:///android_asset"

Answer (score 4):

This is the best solution for GIF in Android :

Insert the following dependency to build.gradle file of your project.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
}
```

then

```
The simplest way is to use GifImageView 

<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/src_anim"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_anim"
    />
```

If drawables declared by **android:src** and/or **android:backgroun**d are GIF files then they will be **automatically recognized as GifDrawables** and animated. If given drawable is not a GIF then mentioned Views work like plain ImageView and ImageButton.

https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score 3):

Loads gif in a webview and fits it to the device screen without any HTML code...Try this code

```
mWebView = ((CustomWebView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.webview));
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.gif");
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any HTML code... Just use this line

```
webViewControl.LoadUrl("file://" + pathToTheGifFile);
```

It Works for Me.

Answer (score 1):

yes this is the right that gif not support in android 
Another solution As [`TRonZ`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1448308/tronz) WebView supports gif , just `make a WebView` and `load the URL of the gif image` and you are done

Comment: Even in 2.3 GIF is not being supporteD?

Comment: Hey but the WebView supports gif , just make a WebView and load the URL of the gif image and you are done .

Answer (score 0):

Save your GIF file at Assets folder. Here "loading.gif" is the filename.

```
    WebView webView=new WebView();
    Content = webView;

    webView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
        Html = $"<body\"><img src=\"loading.gif\"/></body>"
    };
```