# What does file:///android_asset/www/index.html mean?

Tags: android

I want to know what does `file:///` mean while loading a html file from the assets folder in android

Is it an absolute path name which points to the root directory?

I saw this in the tutorial for phonegap by the way.

Comment: Better question: Where does `file:///android_assets/` point to in project structure?

Comment: @user300375 found the answer?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`file:///` is a URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) that simply distinguishes from the standard URI that we all know of too well - `http://`.

It does imply an absolute path name pointing to the root directory in any environment, but  in the context of Android, it's a convention to tell the Android run-time to say "*Here, the directory `www` has a file called `index.html` located in the `assets` folder in the **root** of the project*".

That is how assets are loaded at runtime, for example, a `WebView` widget would know exactly where to load the embedded resource file by specifying the `file:///` URI.

Consider the code example:

```
WebView webViewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewer);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

A very easy mistake to make here is this, some would infer it to as `file:///android_assets`, notice the plural of assets in the URI and wonder why the embedded resource is not working!

Comment: "asset" verses "assets" was an error that took me hours to solve on my first PhoneGap/Android project. Your solution helped me realize what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Do I have to create this folder or where exactly is localize?

Comment: You create that in `/res` a folder called `assets`.

Comment: Why does it use three slashes?

Comment: @MichaelLevy see http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-kerwin-file-scheme-06 on Page 4 for your answer. It is a widely adopted de-facto standard for Uri naming conventions in regards to filesystems. Also, see http://superuser.com/questions/352133/why-do-file-urls-start-with-3-slashes as well.

Comment: So is the directory structure in this case /res/assets/android_asset/www/index.html then? @t0mm13b

Answer (score 19):

If someone uses AndroidStudio make sure that the assets folder is placed in

1. **app/src/main/assets**

   directory.

Comment: What about for `androidTest` instrumented tests?

Answer (score 17):

The URI `"file:///android_asset/"` points to `YourProject/app/src/main/assets/`.

*Note: `android_asset/` uses the singular (asset) and `src/main/assets` uses the plural (assets).*

Suppose you have a file `YourProject/app/src/main/assets/web_thing.html` that you would like to display in a WebView. You can refer to it like this:

```
WebView webViewer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewer);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web_thing.html");
```

The snippet above could be located in your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class, possibly in the `onCreate` method.

Here is a [guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) to the overall directory structure of an android project, that helped me figure out this answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is actually called `file:///android_asset/index.html`

`file:///android_assets/index.html` will give you a build error.

Comment: Holy correct : this answer + the previous answer of (app/src/main/assets)

Answer (score 0):

It took me more than 4 hours to fix this problem. I followed the guide from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

I'm using Android Studio (Eclipse with ADT could not work properly because of the build problem).

Solution that worked for me:

1. I put the /assets/www/index.html under app/src/main/assets directory. (take care AndroidStudio has different perspectives like Project or Android)
2. use super.loadUrl("file:///**android_asset**/www/index.html"); instead of super.loadUrl("file:///**android_assets**/www/index.html"); (no **s**)

Answer (score 0):

it's file:///**android_asset**/...  not file:///**android_assets**/... notice the plural of assets is wrong even if your file name is assets

Comment: Duplicate of answer provided 3 years prior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21242233/1549818