# how to use android_asset

Tags: android, webview, android-assets

I try to make Webview from to display application/x-shockwave-flash embed element in my app, but i have blank gray screen on emulator and white on device. There are many topics about this problem but any1 really solved.

I explore log of simillar app and see: file//android_asset/index.html. So question... this static file or i can get it from web or modify it. 
I trying get my data  video.loadDataWithBaseURL() from web, but can i have that data from local storage?
Maybe I said something wron but it's look for me like 'convert web data to local'?? Can some one help my in my problem or explain in this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does file:///android\_asset/www/index.html mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961975/what-does-file-android-asset-www-index-html-mean)

Answer (score 4):

`file://android_asset/` is a way that allows android apps access `assets` by a network-based URI. But `assets` represent neither local nor online files, they are packed into your apk. Put any files in `assets` folder in a android project and they will be packed into the apk file by the builder.