# Looking for a file doesn't work without "file:"

Tags: java, path, testng, mockito

I'm testing web-flow, and i need to found xml file that contains application's flow. But I really don't understand why is necessary put file: before the path, why is this necessary?

declaration path:

```
protected static final String ARREL_FLOWS = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flow/";
protected static final String FLOW_CONSULTA_DEUTE = ARREL_FLOWS +"consultaDeutes/consultaDeutes.xml";
```

Code to test the path flow:

```
@Test
    @Override
    protected FlowDefinitionResource getResource(FlowDefinitionResourceFactory resourceFactory) {
         FlowDefinitionResource resource = resourceFactory.createResource(FLOW_CONSULTA_DEUTE);
         Assert.assertNotNull(resource);
         return resource;
     }
```

this is py project estrucuture:
[image]

ty.

Comment: You will find an explanation of `file://` in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961975/what-does-file-android-assets-www-index-html-mean

Comment: it's not really the same issue but ty, my problem is that in another project a don't need put the word file:..i just wanna know to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I find out why! i feel like a monkey..
well:

If don't wanna put the word file: i necessary use the method:

```
  resource = resourceFactory.createFileResource(getPathRecursFlowProvatura());
```

not

```
FlowDefinitionResource resource = resourceFactory.createResource(FLOW_CONSULTA_DEUTE);
```

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/web-flow/65371-class-path-resource-file-not-found-error-while-running-junit