# application error net::err_file_not_found(file:///android_asset/www/home.html)

Tags: android, cordova

If I launch the app on my android phone the start up page (index.html) loads but if I try to navigate to another page it pops up the error  application error net::err_file_not_found(file:///android_asset/www/home.html) but it is working fine on system browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does file:///android\_assets/www/index.html mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961975/what-does-file-android-assets-www-index-html-mean)

Comment: Publish your code to see more details...