# Animated GIF Freezes in WebView while timer is running

Tags: android, android-webview, countdowntimer

I have a WebView with an animated gif loaded in it. I also have a countdown timer and when it's up it loads a different animated gif.

When the timer is running the gif doesn't animated. What is the best way to fix this?

```
public class Practice extends SherlockActivity implements
    AnimationLayout.Listener {
public final static String TAG = "Practice";

protected ListView mList;
protected AnimationLayout mLayout;
protected String[] mStrings = { "Lesson 1", "Lesson 2", "Lesson 3",
        "Lesson 4", "Lesson 5", "Lesson 6", "Lesson 7", "Lesson 8",
        "Lesson 9", "Lesson 10" };
String[] lesson1;
String[] lesson2;
String[] lesson3;
String[] lesson4;
String[] lesson5;
String[] lesson6;
String[] lesson7;
String[] lesson8;
String[] lesson9;
String[] lesson10;
Button buttonA;
Button buttonB;
Button buttonC;
Button buttonD;
String[] prev;
int numCorrect;
int numWrong;
int i;
String answer;
static Random rnd;
Random r;
final String alphabet = "ABCD";
final int N = 4;
char letter = 'A';
String rand = " ";
int index;
WebView sign;
long mMilliseconds = 10000;
TextView score;

CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mMilliseconds, 10){
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        score.setText("0");
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        score.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/100));
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice);

    prev = new String[100];
    rnd = new Random();
    r = new Random();
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    lesson1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_1);
    lesson2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_2);
    lesson3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_3);
    lesson4 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_4);
    lesson5 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_5);
    lesson6 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_6);
    lesson7 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_7);
    lesson8 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_8);
    lesson9 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_9);
    lesson10 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.lesson_10);

    rand = lesson1[rnd.nextInt(lesson1.length)];

    mLayout = (AnimationLayout) findViewById(R.id.animation_layout);
    mLayout.setListener(this);

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sidebar_list);
    mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mStrings));
    mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mList.setItemChecked(0, true);

    sign = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
    sign = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option1_button);
    buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option2_button);
    buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option3_button);
    buttonD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option4_button);

    setSign();
}

public void onClickContentButton(View v) {
    mLayout.toggleSidebar();
}

public void onClickA(View v) {
    if (answer == buttonA.getText().toString()) {
        numCorrect += 1;
    } else {
        numWrong += 1;
    }

    setSign();
}

public void onClickB(View v) {
    if (answer == buttonB.getText().toString()) {
        numCorrect += 1;
    } else {
        numWrong += 1;
    }

    setSign();
}

public void onClickC(View v) {
    if (answer == buttonC.getText().toString()) {
        numCorrect += 1;
    } else {
        numWrong += 1;
    }

    setSign();
}

public void onClickD(View v) {
    if (answer == buttonD.getText().toString()) {
        numCorrect += 1;
    } else {
        numWrong += 1;
    }

    setSign();
}

public void onClick(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mLayout.isOpening()) {
        mLayout.closeSidebar();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSidebarOpened() {
    Log.d(TAG, "opened");
}

@Override
public void onSidebarClosed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "opened");
}

@Override
public boolean onContentTouchedWhenOpening() {
    Log.d(TAG, "going to close sidebar");
    mLayout.closeSidebar();
    return true;
}

public void setSign() {

    answer = pickRandomAnswer(prev[i]);

    letter = alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(N));

    sign.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + answer.toLowerCase() + ".html");

    prev[i] = answer;

    buttonA.setText(pickRandomAnswer(answer));
    buttonB.setText(pickRandomAnswer(buttonA.getText().toString()));
    buttonC.setText(pickRandomAnswer(buttonB.getText().toString()));
    buttonD.setText(pickRandomAnswer(buttonC.getText().toString()));

    if (letter == 'A')
        buttonA.setText(answer);
    if (letter == 'B')
        buttonB.setText(answer);
    if (letter == 'C')
        buttonC.setText(answer);
    if (letter == 'D')
        buttonD.setText(answer);

    if(i>= 95){
        i = 0;
    } else {
        i += 1;
    }
    mCountDownTimer.start();
}


public String pickRandomAnswer(String str) {

    do{
        index = rnd.nextInt(10+1);

        if(index == 1){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(0)){
                rand = lesson1[rnd.nextInt(lesson1.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 2){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(1)){
                rand = lesson2[rnd.nextInt(lesson2.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 3){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(2)){
                rand = lesson3[rnd.nextInt(lesson3.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 4){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(3)){
                rand = lesson4[rnd.nextInt(lesson4.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 5){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(4)){
                rand = lesson5[rnd.nextInt(lesson5.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 6){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(5)){
                rand = lesson6[rnd.nextInt(lesson6.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 7){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(6)){
                rand = lesson7[rnd.nextInt(lesson7.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 8){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(7)){
                rand = lesson8[rnd.nextInt(lesson8.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 9){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(8)){
                rand = lesson9[rnd.nextInt(lesson9.length)];
            }
        }

        if(index == 10){
            if(mList.isItemChecked(9)){
                rand = lesson10[rnd.nextInt(lesson10.length)];
            }
        }

    } while ( rand.contains("Grammar")| rand == str);
    return rand;
}

static void shuffleArray(String[] words) {
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        String a = words[index];
        words[index] = words[i];
        words[i] = a;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think this link will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4826894/2021499

Comment: show some code how you have implemented it

Comment: I added my code. I still haven't been able to fix this problem

Comment: Can you please change `new CountDownTimer(mMilliseconds, 10)` to `new CountDownTimer(mMilliseconds, 1000)`?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib I have tried that and it has not changed anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your code one possible reason for your issue is that you are updating a `TextView` in the UI on every call of the `onTick()` method of the `CountDownTimer`. The documentation for `CountDownTimer` only mentions that it is called "at a regular interval" so I'm not sure how often it is called, but it seems to me that you shouldn't do something that updates the UI on every `onTick()` call, especially when you have a `WebView` animating a gif (a rather resource intensive task). I suggest doing this in your `onTick()` method:

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
   if (mLastMillisUntilFinished == 0 ||
       mLastMillisUntilFinished - millisUntilFinished > UI_UPDATE_INTERVAL) {
       score.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/UI_UPDATE_INTERVAL));
       mLastMillisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
   }
}
```

This way you are only updating the UI every `UI_UPDATE_INTERVAL` milliseconds (just define that to your desired interval, like 100 in your case to update every 10th of a second). This protects you from unnecessarily updating the UI too often and will allow the `WebView` to do it's job.

As a last resort, there is a more complicated (no too complicated) solution that should get you the performance you want. See this `GifView` class in one of my github repos:

> https://github.com/bduncavage/catoverflow/blob/master/src/jp/tomorrowkey/android/gifplayer/GifView.java

I found that class in an abandoned project on google code and used it in a project that required I draw animated gifs to a Canvas. It needed serious work as it was not threadsafe at all, and it hogs memory, BUT, it does work.

You can use GifView pretty easily and it should be much faster than using a WebView just to animate a gif. You will need the [GifDecoder](https://github.com/bduncavage/catoverflow/blob/master/src/jp/tomorrowkey/android/gifplayer/GifDecoder.java) class as well.

Cheers.

Comment: Updating the UI helps but it help 100%, more like 30% - 40%. The second solution doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hm, must be that `onTick()` is called on the main thread (hence why it that suggested change does nothing). It was a bit of stretch on my part. I'll update my answer to remove that. Let me think on this a bit more.

Comment: Ok, updated with another alternative solution, let me now how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort I would say you can also split your GIFs into frames then render them in android using drawables.
[Drawables reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Comment: This would take to long as I plan to have a few thousand animated gifs.