# Read Gif Images using WebView android

Tags: android, webview, gif

When I try to read a gif images using a WebView in Android 2.3.3 API 10, it's not animated (it appears static). How can I solve this issue? Is there any setting I must change?

ActivtiyMain.xml:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" 
    />
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public WebView Wv;

Wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
Wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/bet.gif");
```

bet.gif: gif images added to the assets folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are trying to load gif from assets directory, its not animated, you should use GifWebView for this.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#da4040" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewActionView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.test2;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webviewActionView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = getAssets().open("loading2.gif");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        webviewActionView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewActionView);
        webviewActionView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webviewActionView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, stream);
        webviewActionView.addView(view);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

GifWebView.java

```
package com.test2;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.View;

public class GifWebView extends View {
    private Movie mMovie;
    InputStream mStream;
    long mMoviestart;

    public GifWebView(Context context, InputStream stream) {
        super(context);
        mStream = stream;
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mMoviestart == 0) {
            mMoviestart = now;
        }
        final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

*Put "**loading2.gif**" file in your assets directory.*

Download this full deom from below link

[Download Demo](http://www.mediafire.com/?01ji789xqs5c2zj)

Comment: @Ajay_Adddon: exactly, describe at least what is wrong with the question/what your answer solves, providing the essential things that need to change to get the requested animation going. An additional link to a full working example is a bonus, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Ajay_Addon the image is on the top left corner how to align it to center?

Comment: it works for me, but for different screen size i want different size of webview, i cant make it with it,

Comment: In my tests, if the animated gif uses delta frames, the `Movie` class doesn't play them properly in versions of Android OS before 4.0.

Answer (score 5):

To use GIF in your android code,

**Step 1:** Assets  folder setting :
 In this folder you have to place your GIF and html code.
Html code is following

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>body{margin:auto auto;text-align:center;} img{width:100%25;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="splash.gif" width="100%"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code lets assume you have splash.gif in ur assets folder

**Step 2:** Just load the webview with this url

**wvSplashScreen.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/splash.html");**

By these 2 simple step you can load GIF in your webview

Answer (score 0):

Animated gif's aren't supported yet, although they work on some devices. See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825383/gif-image-display-using-webview)?

To quote this user @Kantesh:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="white">
    <table width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <font color="gray">Some text you display</font>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <img src="yourGIF.gif">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```