# How to play gif in android from url?

Tags: android, animated-gif

I want to play animated gif from url in android app like imgur app. Imagur is superb and very fast. I am loading gif with webview but its not up to the mark.

Comment: you can use glide library. project plaid by nick butcher shows how you can show gifs.https://github.com/nickbutcher/plaid

Comment: Refers these links for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660209/display-animated-gif           And another one id that http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/14/tutorial-how-to-use-animated-gifs-in-android-part-1/

Comment: I tried glide also but its not working.

Comment: try gifview lib: https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView

Comment: Ok let me try all the above links. Hope one should work properly.

Comment: try it using videoView

Answer (score 17):

You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to play gif on `ImageView`. So, let's add it to your app's gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
}
```

Then, create an `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your activity:

```
Glide  
    .with(context) // replace with 'this' if it's in activity
    .load("http://www.google.com/.../image.gif")
    .asGif()
    .error(R.drawable.error_image) // show error drawable if the image is not a gif
    .into(R.id.imageView);
```

For more information, open this post [Glide — Displaying Gifs & Videos](https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos).

Comment: Thank you Its working but taking time. I need quick output.

Comment: @user3606902, You can use `WebView` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21018730/3922207

Comment: It is taking time because first it gets downloaded in the cache. If you want quick output, pack it in your apk in assets folder and access it from there.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to display animated GIF directly from URL to your app layout is to use WebView class.

Step 1: **In your layout XML**

```html
<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
/>
```

Step 2: **In your Activity**

```js
WebView wb;
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
wb.loadUrl("https://.......);
```

Step 3: **In your Manifest.XML make Internet permission**

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Step 4: **In case you want to make your GIF background transparent and make GIF fit to your Layout**

```js
wb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello everyone how asking about showing gif from url in android studio just follow my lead:

**First** we are about to use glide library so we need to  implement the dependencie

```
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

**second** thing to do after sync your gradle is go the your xml and create a new imageView

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

and **finally** go to your mainActivity or activity that realated to this xml :
first declare ImageView and find the id in onCreate like this:

```
public ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView=findViewById(R.id.image_id);
```

and the last thing is using glide library to show the gif yes of course from Url :

```
 Glide.with(this).load("https://media.giphy.com/media/xT5LMJmXRmrn3ft04w/giphy.gif").into(imageView);
```

that's it **but** if you want to use the gif from your drawable use this line instead :

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.imageGif).into(imageView);
```

This is the ***Glide library*** here:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

You can set imageview as like :

```
           <com.example.androidgif.GifView
            android:id="@+id/gifview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Following this tutorial you can do it :

http://android-er.blogspot.de/2014/03/load-animated-gif-from-internet.html